# select rows from table where other columns do not match

Tags: mysql

I have this  MySQL tabl's colmns which has around 9000 rows:

```
number | description | Bronze | Gold | Silver | Platinum
```

How can I select rows where columns *Gold*, *Silver* and *Platinum* that are not equal the value of *Bronze*

I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `callplandata` WHERE `Silver` != `Bronze` AND `Gold` != `Bronze`
```

but it returns no rows even it should return:

```
number  description           Bronze  Silver  Gold
441     UK Local / National   1.2     0.893   0.7
```

Comment: Create an SQLFiddle please that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Do as Begueradj suggested , you can also see last example of this link to get the idea to do it  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/row-subqueries.html

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks OK, although I find the quoting around fields odd.

The principle is correct - within a select statement you can just compare the values of one field to another with `!=` or `=`

Maybe there is some rounding happening, or other problems with precision that mean that the values you have look the same, but are not exactly equivalent? You don't mention the field types - is it possible they're similar but not equivalent floats, or are being rounded to lower precision when you select them?

Also beware of NULL values, as they don't work as you'd expect with numeric comparisons.

I just ran this test code locally, it all works as you'd expect. Note I used fixed numeric precision.

```
mysql> create table testit ( number int, description text, Bronze numeric(10,5), Silver numeric(10,5), Gold numeric(10,5), Platinum numeric(10,5) );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> insert into testit values (441,'UK Local / National',1.2 ,0.893,0.7, null ) ;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.16 sec)

mysql> select * from testit;
+--------+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+----------+
| number | description         | Bronze  | Silver  | Gold    | Platinum |
+--------+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+----------+
|    441 | UK Local / National | 1.20000 | 0.89300 | 0.70000 |     NULL |
+--------+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT *  FROM testit  WHERE  Gold != Bronze AND Silver != Bronze;
+--------+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+----------+
| number | description         | Bronze  | Silver  | Gold    | Platinum |
+--------+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+----------+
|    441 | UK Local / National | 1.20000 | 0.89300 | 0.70000 |     NULL |
+--------+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```